# jquery - resetting down arrow key counter

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to navigate the autocomplete dropdown using arrow keys.

**JSON**

```
{
    "employees":[
        {
            "name": "Alex"
        },
        {
            "name": "Alice"
        },  
        {
            "name": "Brian"
        },
        {
            "name": "Betsy"
        },
        {
            "name": "Beck"
        },
        {
            "name": "Bob"
        },
        {
            "name": "Brad"
        },
        {
            "name": "Brown"
        }
    ]
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
        <style>
            .selected{background-color:pink;}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var keyCounter = -1;
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "myjson.json",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: "true",
                    contentType: "application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8",
                    cache: "false",
                    success: function(response){
                        $("input#myInput").live("keyup", function(e){

                            var myInputVal = $("input#myInput").val();
                            var myInputValLen = $("input#myInput").val().length;

                            $("ul#myList").empty();

                            for (var x = 0; x < response.employees.length; x++) {

                                var empName = response.employees[x].name;

                                if (empName.substring(0, myInputValLen).toLowerCase().search(myInputVal.substring(0, myInputValLen).toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                                    $("ul#myList").append("<li>" + empName + "</li>");
                                }                                                           
                            }
                            if (e.keyCode == 40) {                          
                                var keyCnter = keyCounter;                      
                                var listLen = $("li").length;                           
                                if (keyCnter != listLen - 1) {
                                    keyCnter++;
                                    $("li").removeClass("selected");
                                    $("li").eq(keyCnter).addClass("selected");                                  
                                    keyCounter = keyCnter;
                                }               
                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
            })
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" width="25" id="myInput">
        <ul id="myList" style="margin:0px;"></ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

**STEPS TO REPLICATE**

1. type in "b" in the text field. the drop down displays 6 names starting with "b"
2. use down arrow key to navigate to "Betsy"
3. type in "r" after "b" in the text field. the drop down displays 3 names starting with "br"
4. use down arrow key to navigate. "Brown" is highlighted. Instead, "Brian" should be highlighted.

*How can I reset the counter to -1?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entirely untested, but would it make sense to just reset it to -1 if anything other than down arrow is pressed?

```
if (e.keyCode == 40) {
    ...
} else {
    keyCounter = -1;
}
```

Comment: Please re-read the question and steps to replicate. I'm using the down arrow key for navigation.

Comment: I agree with @Sheldon, may need to reset it at beginning of handler...put a fiddle together for this

Comment: I'm fairly certain I have the logic correct - the user will either be typing in the text box (in which case the keycounter will be -1) or hitting "down arrow, down arrow, down arrow". If they stop hitting down arrow and start typing anything else, don't you want the index to reset?

Comment: @Sheldon: Yes, I want the index to be reset. But my problem is -- If they stop hitting down arrow -> then start typing in the text field -> then hit down arrow again -> the index should be reset. I tried your solution and it's not working. Please try the steps in my post.

Comment: Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/NQjYK/1/ - as best as I can tell, this works as you're wanting, and the only (functional) difference is the addition I suggested. I type b, down down, r, down down down to get to Brown. If you remove the "else {key.." and run again you'll find it reverts to your current behavior.

Comment: @Sheldon: I copied over from your demo and it works..?!? Sorry, I may have been doing something wrong while trying your solution. Thank you for your help and time.